# Pass state from parent function component to child class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hi I'm trying to pass a value from parent to child so that whenever the parent state changes the child gets the value and re-renders the view. But with the below code the the value is moved from parent to child only once and then hangs indefinitely.

This is the parent function component

```js
export default function App() {  
 const [link, setLink ] = useState("");

 useEffect(() => {
    responseListener.current = 
    Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
    let pushLink = JSON.stringify(response.notification.request.content.data.url)
    setLink(pushLink);
  }
}, []);
}

// Send to child class component
const androidPlatform = <AndBrowser link = {link} />;
 <View style={styles.browser}>
            {Platform.OS === 'ios'? iOSPlatform : androidPlatform}
 </View>
```

Then the child class component

```js
class AndBrowser extends Component {
  // PUSH_URL LINK
  //--------------------------------------
    constructor(props) {
     
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          viewLink : this.props.link,
        }
      //   console.log('test------'+this.props.link);
    }
  //--------------------------------------
 render() {
    if(this.props.link!=undefined){
       linked_url = encodeURI(this.props.link);
    }
 return ( 
      <WebView
        source={{ uri :linked_url }}/>
 );
```

Not sure how to make this work.

Comment: Storing passed props in local state is generally an anti-pattern in React. What is the purpose for saving `link` locally in the child?

Comment: just set , `responseListener.current` ini `useEffect` function

Comment: I'm sending a deep link url which I received from push to render in a webview container.  source={{ uri : linked_url }}

Comment: responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
    let pushLink = JSON.stringify(response.notification.request.content.data.url)
    setLink(pushLink);
} is currently wrapped around useEffect but this doesnt't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

It will rerender when you try using without state like below

```
class AndBrowser extends Component {
   render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: this.props.link }} />;
  }
}
```

You can also try to rerender it by resetting the state from parent to child.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried this through  render() {
//--------------------------
    console.log('4---'+this.props.link);
    if(this.props.link==undefined){
    }else{
        linked_url = encodeURI(this.props.link);
    }  
    console.log('teststate '+linked_url);
//--------------------------   return ( 

      <WebView   source={{ uri :linked_url }} > but it only works once when I the app is exited and on the first push response. On the second push  console.log('4---'+this.props.link); won't print at all. Tried both this.state.url and this.props.url